# Iterative pde solution NDSolve && NIntegrate

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I try to solve a diffusion pde depending on a timedependent argument.

Step by step I have no problem to evaluate several solutions:

**first step (timefunction 0):**

```
tsim=10
U0 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ] - NeumannValue[u[t, x] , x == 1 ] + #  NeumannValue[1, x == 1 ], u[0, x] == 100 }, u , {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1} ] &  [0]
```

**second step:**

From result U0[t,x]  a  new timefunction `int[t]` is calculated

```
 int[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[U0[t, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

which is used to calculate the next solution.

**third step (timefunction int[t]):**

```
U1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ] -  
NeumannValue[u[t, x] , x == 1 ] + #  NeumannValue[1, x == 1 ], u[0, x] == 100 }, u , {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1} ] &  [int[t]]
```

Step 1-3 work fine ...

To easily automate these steps (iteration `U[i][t,x]-> int[i][t]->U[i+1][t,x]->...` I would like to use `NestList` but didn't succeed.

So far I tried

```
NestList[U =NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] ==D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ] -  
NeumannValue[u[t, x] , x == 1 ] + #   NeumannValue[1, x == 1 ] , u[0, x] == 100 }, u , {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1} ] & ;
NIntegrate[U[t, x], {x, 0, 1}]   
, 0, 3]
```

but Mathematica gives error messages `NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.},{0.,1.}},{5,4225,1,{106,41},{4,3},0,0,0,0,Indeterminate&,<<3>>},{{0.,<<9>>,<<96>>},<<1>>},{{{100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,100.,<<31>>},{169.706,29.1169,4.99567,0.857121,0.147059,0.0252312,0.00432868,0.000740845,0.000116391,-0.0000424981,<<31>>}},<<9>>,<<96>>},{Automatic,Automatic}] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.`

Thanks!

**addendum**

I would like to know from other Mathematica v12.2 users, wether the code

```
tsim=2; (* I assume this is a global variable with numerical value *)

U[i_/;i>=1]:=U[i]=With[{aux=int[i-1][t]},NDSolveValue[{D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],{x,2}]+NeumannValue[1,x==0]-NeumannValue[u[t,x],x==1]+aux* NeumannValue[1,x==1],u[0,x]==100},u,{t,0,tsim},{x,0,1}]];
int[i_][t_?NumericQ]:=If[i==0,0,NIntegrate[U[i][t,x],{x,0,1}]];

Table[U[i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

from user293787's very helpful answer is evaluable  !

Thanks again

Comment: Why don't you use ParametricNDSolve?

Comment: @user21 I wasn't sure how to use `ParametricNDSolve` with   function .

Comment: @user21 Do you have an idea what could be the reason that  user293787 's answer doesn't evaluate on Mathematica v12.2 (error NeumannValue...)? Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't know what the issue might be.

Comment: @user21 What a pity, I had the hope `NeumannValue` (changes v12.2 to v12.3) might be the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have v12.2 as well on my computer, therefore we can test code @
user293787, we have

```
tsim = 2;
U[i_ /; i >= 1] := 
 U[i] = With[{aux = int[i - 1][t]}, 
   NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
      D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1, x == 0] - 
       NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 1] + aux*NeumannValue[1, x == 1], 
     u[0, x] == 100}, u, {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}]];
int[i_][t_?NumericQ] := 
  If[i == 0, 0, NIntegrate[U[i][t, x], {x, 0, 1}]];
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[U[i][t, x], {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  MeshStyle -> White], {i, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Code working nice and fast. We can compare solution with my code

```
tsim = 10; 
int[0][t_] := 100; Do[
 U1[i] = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
     D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1., x == 0.] - 
      NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 1] + 
      int[i - 1][t] NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0, x] == 100}, 
   u, {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}]; 
 int[i] = Interpolation[
   Table[{t, NIntegrate[U1[i][t, x], {x, 0, 1}]}, {t, 0, 
     tsim, .1}]], {i, 5}]

Table[Plot3D[U1[i][t, x], {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  MeshStyle -> White], {i, 5}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Now we combine two solutions in one plot

```
tab = Table[{t, U[10][t, .5]}, {t, 0, 2, .1}]
Show[Plot[U1[5][t, .5], {t, 0, 2}], ListPlot[tab, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Finally we can improve code proposed by Ulrich Neumann as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1, {x}]; mesH = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 2.5 10^-2];

tsim = 10; sol = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
    D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1., x == 0.] - 
     NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 1] + 
     100 NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0, x] == 100}, 
  u[t, x], {t, 0, tsim}, Element[{x}, mesH]];

list = NestList[
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
      D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1., x == 0.] - 
       NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 1] + 
       NIntegrate[# /. x -> x1, Element[{x1}, mesH]] NeumannValue[1, 
         x == 1], u[0, x] == 100}, u[t, x], {t, 0, tsim}, 
    Element[{x}, mesH]] &, sol, 10]
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[list[[i]], {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  MeshStyle -> White], {i, 10}]
```

[image: Fugure 4]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer and the confirmation "code runs on v12."  . Now code also runs on my computer, no idea why...  Interesting idea using Ìnterpoaltion( I tried FunctionInterpolation too)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You are welcome! It looks like code with `NestList` not working in version 13.1 as well.

Comment: I played around with the options of `NIntegrate` until `NestList` worked. Don't know what changed from v12.2 to v13.1

Comment: Very clever to force integration to FEM mesh. Thanks.

Comment: Until now my nestlist version is fastest on v12.2. Improvement is only ne essary for newer version

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile I found a smart solution using `NestList` which is worth to be presented I think:

```
list=NestList[NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] ==D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[1., x == 0.] -  NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 1] +
NIntegrate[#[t, x], {x, 0, 1} ,Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 5 ] NeumannValue[1, x == 1], 
u[0, x] == 100}, u, {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}] &, 0 &, 10] // Quiet 

Plot3D[ Evaluate[Through[Rest[liste][t, x]]], {t, 0, tsim}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) but code needs to be improved as well. See update to my answer.

Comment: +1 And Btw, please feel free to move the green checkmark to @AlexTrounev's much more comprehensive answer (or to your own).

Comment: @user293787 It is not easy for me to follow your advice because your fast answer was the starting point of this interesting discussion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
tsim=2; (* I assume this is a global variable with numerical value *)

U[i_/;i>=1]:=U[i]=With[{aux=int[i-1][t]},
                     NDSolveValue[{D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],{x,2}]+NeumannValue[1,x==0]-NeumannValue[u[t,x],x==1]+aux* NeumannValue[1,x==1],u[0,x]==100},u,{t,0,tsim},{x,0,1}]];
int[i_][t_?NumericQ]:=If[i==0,0,NIntegrate[U[i][t,x],{x,0,1}]];
```

**Edit.** The above code and `Table[U[i],{i,1,3}]` runs without warning in Version 12.3. But OP seems to get warnings related to `NeumannValue[...,x==1]`. Here is an alternative version where both `NeumannValue[...,x==1]` are combined into one, it also runs on my machine and seems to give identical results:

```
tsim=2; (* I assume this is a global variable with numerical value *)

U[i_/;i>=1]:=U[i]=With[{aux=int[i-1][t]},
                     NDSolveValue[{D[u[t,x],t]==D[u[t,x],{x,2}]+NeumannValue[1,x==0]+NeumannValue[aux-u[t,x],x==1],u[0,x]==100},u,{t,0,tsim},{x,0,1}]];
int[i_][t_?NumericQ]:=If[i==0,0,NIntegrate[U[i][t,x],{x,0,1}]];
```

Note that [NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) is a relatively new command, and was updated in Version 12.2.

Comment: Nice idea , thanks. But unfortunately `Table[U[i], {i, 1, 3}]` doesn't evaluate.

Comment: Really? It does on my machine. Takes about 2 seconds and returns a list of three `InterpolatingFunctions`.

Comment: What's your Mathematica version? (mine: v12.2)

Comment: V12.3. But nothing here should depend on recent changes I think?

Comment: Trying to evaluate `Table[U[i], {i, 1, 3}]` I get error`NDSolveValue::fembceval: The boundary condition NeumannValue[1,x==1] could not be evaluated numerically.`

Comment: Thanks for your edit.
It remains myserious, `Table[U[i], {i, 1, 3}]` still doesn't evaluate and `int[0][t]` gives `100[t]` !!!

Comment: I would think that can only happen if there are other definitions of `int` still lurking around? I assume you have cleared all relevant variables, perhaps even quit the kernel to be sure. If it does not work, I hope someone more knowledgeable will come along.